# Get cell value of JTable while populating data to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've been developing a GUI Accounting application. I have a `JTable` that populates data of customer over dues as below.

[image]

Please assume I have More customer data and these data are populated to table and I need to show Invoice amount at relevant field (in " Below 30 Days or 31-45 or 46-60 " etc.). I need to do this when I populate data to table.

Comment: Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`, monitor the changes and update the resulting value based on the changes to the model, try not to do a complete recalculation if you can help it...

Comment: there couldn't be required any Listener, answer/suggestion depends of 1. whats (is populate data to jTable.) if you recreating model then Listeners are gone away, 2. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for XxxTableModel in local variable, 3. your effort